# Como definir o valor de uma variável a partir de uma função?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Eu quero algo do tipo, uma função que será passada uma variável como parâmetro e um valor que será aplicada a mesma, tem como fazer isso? Pois o código abaixo não funcionou:

```js
function setVariableValue(variable, value) {
    variable = value;
}

var test; var test2; var test3;

setVariableValue(test, 20);
setVariableValue(test2, "Ola");
setVariableValue(test3, 1000);

document.writeln(test);
document.writeln(test2);
document.writeln(test3);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As variáveis só podem ser alteradas da maneira que queres se puderem ser referenciadas, ou seja se fizerem parte de um *tipo não primitivo*.

Quando usas `function(a, b){` e passas um tipo primitivo à função, só segue o valor com a variável e nenhuma ligação a essa variável fora da função.

Na verdade mesmo passando um não primitivo como `{}` ou  `[]` por exemplo, se fizeres `a = 'foo'` apagas a referência anterior.

**O que podes fazer:**

Aquilo que é possível é alterar propriedades de um não primitivo (`object`, `array`, `function`) dentro da função e isso provocar alterações fora dela.

```js
function sobreEscrever(variable, value) {
  variable = value;
}

function mudarPropriedade(variable, propriedade, value) {
  variable[propriedade] = value;
}

var primitivo = 'foo'
var objeto = {};

sobreEscrever(primitivo, 20);
console.log(primitivo);

sobreEscrever(objeto, "Ola");
console.log(objeto);

var objeto = {};
mudarPropriedade(objeto, 'chave', 1000);
console.log(objeto);
```

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo é que a função `setVariableValue()` recebe apenas *o valor* das variáveis `test`, `test2` e `test3`. Então dentro da função, a sua operação é executada com sucesso, porém em cima de variáveis que deixarão de existir assim que a função retornar (sairão de escopo).

> Por isso, normalmente a gente chama uma função, já atribuindo o resultado à propria variável:

```
test = setVariableValue(test, 20); // atribui o resultado a 'test'
```

Neste caso, sua função deveria ter um `return`:

```js
function setVariableValue(variable, value) {
    // return necessário para que a função retorne algum valor!
    return variable * value;
}

var test = 10;
test = setVariableValue(test, 20);
document.writeln(test); // Resultado: 200
```

> Uma segunda maneira de resolver - Usar a própria variável dentro da função:

```js
var test;
function setVariableValue(value) {
    test = value;
}

setVariableValue(12);
document.writeln(test); // Resultado: 12
```

> E uma terceira maneira - Usando objetos:

```js
function setVariableValue(variable, value) {
    variable.value = value;
}

var test = [], test2 = [], test3 = [];

setVariableValue(test, 20);
setVariableValue(test2, "Ola");
setVariableValue(test3, 1000);

document.writeln(test.value);
document.writeln(test2.value);
document.writeln(test3.value);
```

Como objetos, o que é passado para a função termina sendo uma referência, e ao mudar um atributo deste objeto, a mudança persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da função, use:

```
window[variable] = value;
```

Exemplo

```
function setVariableValue(variable, value) {
    window[variable] = value;
}
```

Para setar o valor

```
test = 30;
console.log(test); // imprime 30

setVariableValue("test", 20); //deve estar delimitado por aspas.

console.log(test); // imprime 20
```

As outras formas apresentadas, em outras respostas, são invasivas pois precisará modificar a estrutura. Preferi manter o mais próximo possível do que precisa. Isso é conhecido como "variáveis variáveis" ou "variável variável".